# How to install/add jconsole to my JDK?

Tags: java, jvm, java-6, jvm-crash

jconsole file is not found in my JDK. How to add/install that?
Could you please any one help me?

Comment: Which platform are you on? How did you install the JDK? Which installer/binary did you use for the installation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried reinstalling the JDK?

Comment: No,, i have to reinstall?,, no there way?

Comment: It might be the easiest way to solve this. Unless you can copy the jconsole binary from another installation.